# jax-ws redirect http / https

Tags: java, soap, webservices-client

I am having problem with jax-ws making it work if the server return 301 on http to https. I got an exception, and after debugging it with charles it seems that the redirect doesn't work. I also noticed that there is some trick for http to https[*], but i am not sure if it still apply to java8

That's the pseudo-code that i would like to use with a dirty fix that i found online

```
    TestImplService service = new TestImplService();
    Test test = service.getTestImplPort();
    Map<String, Object> tmp = ((BindingProvider) test).getRequestContext();

    /*dirty fix*/
    tmp.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, tmp.get(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY).toString().replace("http:", "https:")
    );


    test.dosomething();
```

Replacing http with https work, but i am not 100% sure that's the correct way.

Let's suppose that the server decide to stop to support https, disable the 301 for http, then my fix won't work anymore.

Can i force the follow redirect in another way?

[*] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/upgrade-guide/article-17.html

Comment: Ideally enforcing `http` to `https` should be done on `web-server` like `apache` or `nginx` etc, not in application layer. would like to understand, why you are doing like that, any particular reason?

Comment: unfortunately i have to call a remote service where i have no control of. i already asked to change the http->https but obviusly thy are deaf from this ear... if you know what i mean...

Comment: Instead of `apache`, you could use `nginx`, I think it has body rules support.

Comment: i am the consumer of the webservice, not the producer.

Answer (score 0):

BindingProvider class BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY property is usable for change endpoint URL; Sometimes HTTPS connection ended with network switches/routers. Therefor application server cannot realize the path of https.

```
service = new ....(url, SERVICE_NAME);
port = service.get...BasicHttpEndpoint();
BindingProvider provider = ((BindingProvider) port);
Map<String, Object> map = provider.getRequestContext();
String current = map.get(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY).toString();
map.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, current.replace("http:", "https:"));
```